# Use Auth in AppServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need the ID of the user who is logged in to get a photo in the profile table, here I am trying to use View but only in the index function that gets `$profile`, I want all files in the view to have `$profile`

```
public function index(){
  $profil = Profil_user::where('user_id',$auth)->first();
  View::share('profil', $profil);
  return view('user.index');
}
```

I have also tried AppServiceProvider but I get an error in the form of a null value if I don't log in, is there a solution to my problem?

```
public function boot(){
    $auth = Auth::user();
    dd($auth);
}
```

Comment: Here you want to use $profile in all files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exist several way to pass a variable to all views. I explain some ways.

**1.** use middleware for all routes that you need to pass variable to those:

```
create middleware (I named it RootMiddleware)
```

```
php artisan make:middleware RootMiddleware
```

go to `app/Http/Middleware/RootMiddleware.php` and do following example code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if(auth()->check()) {
        $authUser = auth()->user();
        $profil = Profil_user::where('user_id',$authUser->id)->first();

        view()->share([
            'profil', $profil
        ]);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

then must register this middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php` and put this line `'root' => RootMiddleware::class,` to `protected $routeMiddleware` array.

then use this middleware of routes or routes group, for example:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'root'], function (){
    // your routes that need to $profil, of course it can be used for all routers(because in handle function in RootMiddleware you set if
});
```

or set for single root:

```
Route::get('/profile', 'ProfileController@profile')->name('profile')->middleware('RootMiddleware');
```

---

**2.** other way that you pass variable to all views with view composer
    go to `app/Http` and create Composers folder and inside it create `ProfileComposer.php`, inside `ProfileComposer.php` like this:

```
<?php


namespace App\Http\View\Composers;

use Illuminate\View\View;

class ProfileComposer
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $profil = Profil_user::where('user_id', auth()->id)->first();
        $view->with([
            'profil' => $profil
        ]);
    }
}
```

now it's time create your service provider class, I named it `ComposerServiceProvider`
write this command in terminal : `php artisan make:provider ComposerServiceProvider`
after get *Provider created successfully.* message go to `config/app.php` and register your provider with put this `\App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider::class` to providers array.
now go to `app/Providers/ComposerServiceProvider.php` and do like following:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Http\View\Composers\ProfileComposer;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer(
            '*' , ProfileComposer::class // is better in your case use write your views that want to send $profil variable to those
        );

       /* for certain some view */

        //View::composer(
        //    ['profile', 'dashboard'] , ProfileComposer::class
        //);


       /* for single view */

        //View::composer(
        //    'app.user.profile' , ProfileComposer::class
        //);

    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
    }
}
```

---

**3.** is possible that without create a service provider share your variable in `AppServiceProvider`, go to `app/Provider/AppServiceProvider.php` and do as follows:

```
// Using class based composers...
View::composer(
    'profile', 'App\Http\View\Composers\ProfileComposer'
);

// Using Closure based composers...
View::composer('dashboard', function ($view) {
      //
});
```

I hope be useful

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
     view()->composer('*', function($view)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $view->with('currentUser', Auth::user());
        }else {
            $view->with('currentUser', null);
        }
    });
```