# Laravel view into another view

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade

Just started learning Laravel not long ago and I've got a question about views.

I have a 2 view files (blade).

The one which shows the categories from database.

The other one is showing the results of as search in products.

I'd like to use them in the same view, in the first section would be the searcher area and the area below is where I would like to list the categories.

I tried a couple of things to make it work, but I'm not sure which is the right approach:

1. I made a function in a controller where I listed the categories and handled the search and sent that to the view, but i didn't like this approach because I'm handling two different logic in one function.
2. I tried to yield or @include the view file into the main view. I got an error, because the database query didn't happen that case. I think yield and include only available with static data.

So, I'm don't know how to handle that issue properly.

Can someone suggest me a solution for this problem?

Thanks the help in advance!

Comment: How about using ajax to search and update the view?

Answer (score 0):

There can be several way.
You can try to fetch category data inside blade file.
So, for example, in category.blade, you can fetch category list from database.
Then it would be independent to other views file and controllers.
And you can include category.blade.php for example.

The second way, is to fetch category data via ajax.
In this case, you can not insert script in all pages of using category.
So, in this case, you can use template structure.
For example.
In `template.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js css-menubar" lang="en">
    @stack('style')
    @include('admin.layouts.head')
    @include('admin.layouts.header')
    @include('admin.layouts.page')
    @include('admin.layouts.footer')
    @stack('script')
</html>
```

In  `page.blade.php`

```
<div class="page">
    @yield('page-content')
</div>
```

In individual page,

```
@extends('admin.layouts.template' ,['menu'=>'coach'])
@section('insert-css')
  your custom css content here
@endsection
@section('page-content')
  Your page content here
@endsection
```

Comment: my answer below

Comment: I've suggested 2 method for that. So, one is, hmm, in blade file for category list, directly fetch category models. And the second is using ajax from parent blade template file.

Answer (score 0):

You must get `$categories` just once and pass `$categories` to all views (or views that need to category or just pass it to `categories.blade.php`).
for this goal, I suggest that create a partial blade called `categories.blade.php` and show all cateogories in it and include it wherever necessary, but before before that go to `app/Provider/AppServiceProvider.php` and in `boot()` method get categories and share it in categories blade that you created it, like below :

```
public function boot() {
    // pass to first param, address categories blade 
    View()->composer('categories', function ($view){ 
        // set a name for variable that get it in categories view
        $view->with(['categories'=>$categories]);  
    });
}
```

If you would like to know more about subscriptions, visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60466668/use-auth-in-appserviceprovider/60467521#60467521) or  [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views#view-composers)

Comment: This works, that was what I was looking for! Thank you